Power app combobox in edit form not showing desired column
I'm new to power apps and I am trying to add a combobox to a card in an edit form. My backend is an Azure SQL Database. Traditionally the combobox is used to display to the end user a text value rather than the id value in the backend.
I have been scouring documentation on how to use this as such in an edit form replacing the text box that holds the id for a category with the userfriendly text value.
Here are my current inputs:

Card default: ThisItem.UNIT_OF_MEASURE_ID (holds the id to the category table from the datasource)
Card update:  cbo_UnitOfMeas.Selected.ZC_MEAS_UNIT_ID
Combobox datasource  = the category table datasource
Combobox text columns - 2 text columns where one is holding an abbreviation text and the other the full name of the category. I would like to display the abbrevion column when usings are scrolling through records.
Combobox defaultselecteditems: {Value:Parent.Default}

Thank you for any help here!!
I've tried to fiddle with defaultselected items to get something else displayed to no avail.

Try changing DisplayFields property of combo box control to your category name or
abbreviation column. Check: Combo box control in Power Apps. Let me know if this works for you.

I entered ["UNIT_ABBRV"] (which is the text column in the category table I want users to see and now a value shows in the boxes but it is the id value.  This is in edit mode where I am scrolling through existing records. In this state is it the DefaultSelectedItems field that links the main source table to the category table? This master child relationship is not quite clear to me as it would in MS Access.  I have read though all documentation available in MS relating to comboxes with this not quit answered clearly.  Appreciate the help!

Is you combo box single selection or multiple selection? You will have to update Combobox defaultselecteditems or default property accordingly.

Currently the combo box is set to single.   Default has nothing since this is a deprecated field.    DefaultSelectedItems   -> {Value:Parent.Default}  .   Everything is same as in original post  and now I have entered ["UNIT_ABBRV"] in the Display field which did finally produce a value in the combo box but it is the id not the text which would correspond to ["UNIT_ABBRV"].

I was able to get this field to work from changing DefaultSelectedItems value to: LookUp(ZC_MEAS_UNIT,ZC_MEAS_UNIT_ID = Parent.Default) and  now see the appropriate text value in my combobox. The following is the information gathered while researching the problem with my final property values. This works while viewing the results of records already added. I have not tested and addnew state yet.
